# "No match for operator>" when using priority queue in C++

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, priority-queue

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct vert
{
    int n,m;
    vert(int Node1=0,int Node2=0)
    {
        n=Node1,m=Node2;
    }
    bool operator<(vert const &obj)
    {
            return m<obj.m;
    }
};

int main()
{
    priority_queue<vert> q;
    q.push(vert(1,2));
}
```

when I run this code, I get the following error, `error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const vert' and 'const vert')`, I even declare what the operator `<` does, but it still doesn't work, How do I fix this?

Comment: You should _not_ include that header, or anything in "bits/",  as it's nonstandard and internal to a particular implementation.  You should include the real c++ header,  <queue>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, use `const`.

Try this

```
bool operator<(vert const &obj) const
```